# How to pass environment variables in circleci without committing to git

Tags: docker, environment-variables, circleci, dockerhub, circleci-2.0

I have a simple project I am working on.

I am using circleci for my CI/CD pipelines.

When I push a commit the build runs, tests run and IF they pass then the app is packed up into a docker image.

The image is then pushed up to dockerhub, and from here I can just pull the image down in docker compose or kubernetes or whatever.

This all works perfectly.

**My question is *how* can pass the docker-hub credentials to circleci without exposing them to the public by committing them to source control?**

In the past on previous project I feel like I deployed a Serverless framework project out to AWS, and to do this I am sure I stored my AWS creds in circleci somewhere so that I could just reference them safely in my .circleci/config.yml.

This was along time ago and I can't find how to do this.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction with this?

I have provided my config.yml just to illustrate my workflow more succinctly.

```js
version: 2
jobs: 
  build: 
    docker: 
      - image: circleci/golang:1.11
 
    environment:
      TEST_RESULTS: /tmp/test-results

    steps: 
      - checkout
      - run: mkdir -p $TEST_RESULTS

      - restore_cache: 
          keys:
            - v1-pkg-cache
      
      - run: go get github.com/lib/pq
      - run: go get github.com/mattes/migrate
      - run: go get github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report
      - run: go mod download
      - run: go build 

      - run:
          name: Run unit tests
          command: go test ./...

      - save_cache:
          key: v1-pkg-cache
          paths:
            - "/go/pkg"

      - run:
          name: Start service
          command: go run main.go
          background: true 

      - store_artifacts: 
          path: /tmp/test-results
          destination: raw-test-output

      - store_test_results: 
          path: /tmp/test-results

       - setup_remote_docker:
           docker_layer_caching: true

      # TODO: need to pull docker-hub credentials safely from environment variables and then the docker image can be pushed up to dockerhub.
       - run:
           name: build and push container
           command: |
             docker build -t myrepo/im-projects:LATEST -t myrepo/im-projects:v0.0.1 .
             echo $DOCKER_PWD | docker login -u username -p password
             docker push myrepo/im-projects:LATEST
```

Comment: I believe environmental variables are what you are looking for. https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/

Comment: For anyone still looking for a way to manage secrets for your Serverless app, here is a post -
https://seed.run/blog/how-to-manage-secrets-for-your-serverless-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd set private environment variables via the UI. https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-project

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.